# Showing Quotient Ring is a Field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideals

Consider the ring $S=\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$, where $\alpha = \sqrt[3]{2}$, and ideal $I=(5,\alpha^{2}+3\alpha -1)$. I wish to show that $S/I$ is a field of order 25. Any solutions/suggestions? I would like a way to do this without first showing that $I$ is prime.

Comment: Hint: Try to write the general polynomial in $S$ and to "restrict" it to $S/I$, i.e. to impose the relations $5=0$ and $\alpha^2=1-3\alpha$. You will find constraints on the new coefficients.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observe that we have isomorphisms
$$S/I=\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]/(5,\alpha^2+3\alpha-1)\cong\mathbb{Z}[x]/(5,x^3-2,x^2+3x-1)\cong\mathbb{F}_5[x]/(x^3-2,x^2+3x-1).$$
Show that, as elements of $\mathbb{F}_5[x]$,

- $x^2+3x-1$ goes into $x^3-2$, so that the ideal $(x^3-2,x^2+3x-1)$ is just $(x^2+3x-1)$
- $x^2+3x-1$ is irreducible, so that the ideal $(x^2+3x-1)$ is maximal in $\mathbb{F}_5[x]$

Combined with the fact that $\deg(x^2+3x-1)=2$, we see that
$$S/I\cong\mathbb{F}_5[x]/(x^2+3x-1)$$
is a field of order 25.

Comment: Ahh thanks. I was making a calculation error when checking that $x^{2}+3x-1$ was irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$. I was getting $3$ as a root modulo 5 because I wrote down the polynomial at $x^{2}+3x+1$ on my scrap paper.

Comment: Glad I could help :) Though I'd suggest that, in the future, it would be extremely helpful to mention what you've tried on a question - I had no way of knowing from your original post that you already understood everything I wrote. If you had explained in your question that you tried this argument but got that the polynomial wasn't irreducible, it would have been easier to determine that it was a calculation error.